# How to get dataflow job id from inside that dataflow job - JAVA

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In my current architecture, multiple dataflow jobs are triggered at various stages, as part of ABC framework, I need to capture the job id of those jobs as audit metrics inside the dataflow pipeline and update it in BigQuery.

How do I get the run id of dataflow job from the pipeline using JAVA?
Is there any existing method that I can use for that or do I need to use google cloud's client library inside the pipeline for that?

Comment: Can you try to perform an `options.getJobId()`? and let me know if you get what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting to dataflow, I believe this might work:

```
DataflowPipelineJob result = (DataflowPipelineJob)pipeline.run()
result.getJobId()
```

But you cannot access that within the pipeline itself afaik (DoFns etc).

The best way to ensure you know your job id/name, is to set it yourself. You can do this by setting `--jobName` and this is accessible via `options.getJobName()`, dataflow will use this. Note it must be unique.

Comment: I will try this out but I want to update the job id in BQ tables from within the pipeline, will that be possible?

Comment: Yes. If you set it yourself you can pass it onto any transforms and dofns you want at startup. You can also access options from any pcollection, so can can fetch in the expand fn of a transform and pass into a inner class dofn, for example.